# Making a rudimentary program to find pair of closest points and i'm stuck

Tags: coordinates

Ok first off I am obviously a noob and apologize for my backwards thinking or if im not posting correctly im new to the site as well. I am sure there are infinite better ways to go about this but if you could bear with me and help me out that would be great.

The idea is to give each pair of coordinates a distance value and then choose the lowest distance value to find the closest points.

So first off having trouble avoiding duplicates when creating pairs.

I want: AB AC AD AE BC BD BE CD CE DE

but instead getting: AB AC AD AE BA BC BD BE CA CB CD CE DA DB DC DE EA EB EC ED

Second once i find the lowest distance value I can't think of a good way to reference back to the original pair of coordinates. I was thinking about using modulus but idk.

Lastly how to find if there is a tie for closest two.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[][] = new int[5][2];
    int b[] = new int[20];
    int c[] = new int[20];
    int d[] = new int[20];
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++ ) { 
        for (int j = 0 ; j < a[i].length ; j++ ) { 
            a[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++ ) { 
        for (int j = 0 ; j < a[i].length ; j++ ) { 
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++ ) { 
        for (int j = 0 ; j < a.length ; j++ ) {
            if(i == j){}
            else{
            temp =  a[i][0]- a[j][0];
            temp= Math.abs(temp);
            b[count]=temp;
            count++;
            }
        }
    }
    count=0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++ ) { 
        for (int j = 0 ; j < a.length ; j++ ) {
            if(i == j){
            }
            else{
            temp =  a[i][1]- a[j][1];
            temp= Math.abs(temp);
            c[count]=temp;
            count++;
            }
        }
    }        

    for (int i = 0 ; i < b.length ; i++ ) { 
        System.out.println(b[i]+ " " + c[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    for (int i =0 ; i<d.length;i++){
        d[i]=b[i]+c[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < d.length ; i++ ) { 
        System.out.println(d[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < d.length ; i++ ) { 
        if (d[i]== 0){
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }
        else if(d[i]== 1){
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }
        else if (d[i]== 2){
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }

    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force solution would be to have all points in a list, where you then for each point check distance to all other points, saving the pair temporarily if it is the shortest. Once all have been considered, the pair in the temporary variable is the closest ones. This can be slightly optimized to not check duplicates through changing the initial value of the inner loops counter:

```
temp = (null,null,-1);
for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
  p1 = ps[i];
  for (int n=i+1; n < size; n++) { //add 1 as I assume p1,p1 is not a viable pair
    p2 = ps[n]
    dist = |p1-p2|
    if (temp[2] == -1 || dist < temp[2]) {
      temp = (p1, p2, dist);
    }
  }
}
return temp;
```

Other than this, I suggest you start reading about data-structures related to spatial properties (quad-trees, kd-tree etc.). Many games and applications which have points all over the globe use those to ensure you won't have to search through a ridiculously long list of points.

Edit: noticed you also want ties. For this, you could make `temp = [dist, new List<(point,point)>]`, where if `temp[0]==dist` you add the pair to the list `temp[1].add((p1,p2))`. If there is a tie, the list will have more than one element.